# How can I fix this conflict of packages while using Django, Channels, and Heroku?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am following this tutorial on how to deploy a Django+Channels webapp on Heroku, and I've come across a problem when I run the following line:

```
daphne chat.asgi:channel_layer --port 8888
```

I get the following:

```
ERROR: daphne 2.3.0 has requirement asgiref~=3.0, but you'll have asgiref 1.1.2 which is incompatible.
ERROR: channels 2.2.0 has requirement asgiref~=3.0, but you'll have asgiref 1.1.2 which is incompatible.
```

Based on that, I went on to install:

```
pip install asgiref~=3.0
```

However, when I run the daphne line I again, I got:

```
ERROR: asgi-redis 1.4.3 has requirement asgiref~=1.1.2, but you'll have asgiref 3.0.0 which is incompatible.
```

It's my first time tampering with web servers, asynchronicity, and these more complex libraries, so does anyone know how I can fix this problem? The tutorial I am following is this one in case you need:
https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django

Answer (score 2):

Try not to pin the nested dependencies in the requirement file unless absolutely necessary. Removing the other dependencies(asgiref, daphne) from the requirements file and adding only channels should help. Since they are dependecies of channels, pip will look for the appropriate package. Also, asgi-redis is being deprecated in favor of [channels-redis](https://github.com/django/channels_redis) for channels 2, so you should switch to it. It does not depend on asgiref

Comment: I tried removing asgiref and daphne and reinstalling channels but no help, still getting: ERROR: Cannot install asgi-redis==1.4.3 and asgiref==3.5.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

Comment: @Macilias make a new post and paste the contents of your requirements.txt file